# Error When Running Stored Procedure From VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I am using VBA to pull information from SQL Server. To not make things complicated read this:

"I have a Stored Procedure in SQL that receiving a Date (@NeededDate as Date) & a comma delimited text (@DelimitedAssets as NVARCHAR(MAX) returns the required results.

When I run my code in VBA, IT WORKS when the text I'm passing (@DelimitedAssets) is not longer than 7000 characters (that's not the exact number but is close). So, rephrasing this: the code works as expected if the string is not big.

But the text I'm passing to the Stored Procedure from VBA adds up to 12000 characters. NVARCHAR should be able to handle that but is not doing it when I pass it from VBA.

IMPORTANT: if I run the same chunk of data (12000 characters) from SQL Server Management Studio, it works perfectly. No errors and the data is ok.

[image: VBA Error]

ERROR OCCURS IN LINE:

```
Set oRecordSet = .Execute
```

**VBA CODE***

```
Private Function RunMonthlyPricesSP(ByVal strDate As String, ByRef strAssetsDelimted As String, ByRef cnAccounting As Object, ByRef rDestination As Range) As Variant

    Dim oCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim oRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ActivityParam As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim varPrices As Variant
    Dim strAction As String

    Set oCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set oRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

    With oCmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnAccounting
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = "Usp_bondselectionprices"

        .Parameters("@NeededDate").Value = strDate
        .Parameters("@DelimitedAssets").Value = strAssetsDelimted

        Set oRecordSet = .Execute
    End With


    ' Return Array.
    ' Pending.
End Function
```

**SQL STORED PROCEDURE***

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Usp_bondselectionprices]    Script Date: 4/13/2018 5:41:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_bondselectionprices] @NeededDate      DATE,
                                                @DelimitedAssets VARCHAR(max)
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @TblBuysSelectionBond BUYSSELECTIONBONDS

      INSERT INTO @TblBuysSelectionBond
      SELECT *
      FROM   dbo.Splittext(@DelimitedAssets)

      SELECT CASE
               WHEN Prices.Price * CurrencyPrices.Price IS NULL THEN Prices.Price
               ELSE Prices.Price * CurrencyPrices.Price
             END AS Price,
             Assets.AssetName
      FROM   Prices
             INNER JOIN Assets
                     ON Prices.AssetID = Assets.AssetID
             INNER JOIN Assets AS Currencies
                     ON Assets.CurrencyID = Currencies.AssetID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN Prices AS CurrencyPrices
                          ON Currencies.AssetID = CurrencyPrices.AssetID
                             AND Prices.PriceDate = CurrencyPrices.PriceDate
      WHERE  prices.PriceDate = @NeededDate
             AND assets.InstrumentTypeID = 4
             AND Assets.AssetName IN (SELECT *
                                      FROM   @TblBuysSelectionBond)
  END
```

**FUNCTION CALLED FROM STORED PROCEDURE TO CONVERT TEXT DELIMITED INTO A TABLE***

```
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Splittext]    Script Date: 4/13/2018 6:10:02 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Splittext] (@input AS VARCHAR(max))
RETURNS @Result TABLE(
  Value VARCHAR(max))
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)
      DECLARE @ind bigint

      IF( @input IS NOT NULL )
        BEGIN
            SET @ind = Charindex(',', @input)

            WHILE @ind > 0
              BEGIN
                  SET @str = Substring(@input, 1, @ind - 1)
                  SET @input = Substring(@input, @ind + 1, Len(@input) - @ind)

                  INSERT INTO @Result
                  VALUES      (@str)

                  SET @ind = Charindex(',', @input)
              END

            SET @str = @input

            INSERT INTO @Result
            VALUES      (@str)
        END

      RETURN
  END
```

Remember, this works for for small string delimited text. So we know that my connection and other arguments are OK.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution and it's very, very easy. This is why is so important to check the Watch windows to understand what your Objects (oCMD in this case) has inside.

By default it was taking the parameter @DelimitedAssets as adVarChar. You need to specify that it's not a adVarChar but an adLongVarChar.

```
.Parameters("@DelimitedAssets").Value = strAssetsDelimted
.Parameters("@DelimitedAssets").Type = adLongVarChar
```

Once I changed this, everything worked as expected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to specify type&size?

```
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
param.Size = -1;
```

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: setting VBA parameter property